# How to delete an item from a drag and drop menu

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, shopping-cart

I'm trying to add an Delete button function to a drag and drop shopping cart.  I have the button in place but I can not call a function that seems to work.  I'm very novice.

Im not sure if were the function should appear because the list is created from a drag and drop menu

Below is the code so far - any help would be greatly appreciated 
thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>HTML 5 Drag and Drop Shopping Cart</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
     
     <style>
            .products1 { grid-area: products1; }
              .menu1 { grid-area: menu1; }
              .menu2 { grid-area: menu2; }
              .menu3 { grid-area: menu3; }
              .menu4 { grid-area: menu4; }
    
            .grid-container {
             display: grid;
             grid-template-areas:
             'products1 menu1 menu2 menu3 menu4'
              ;
              grid-gap: 5px;
              background-color: #2196F3;
              padding: 5px;
              
      
    }
    
    .grid-container > div {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px 0;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    #item-container{
      width: 280px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 5px solid gray;
      margin:20px auto;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    
      ul, li{
       list-style: none;
       margin: 2px;
       padding: 0px;
       cursor: grabbing;
      }
      section#cart ul{
       height: 600px;
       overflow: auto;
       background-color: #cccccc;
      }
     </style>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
        
      function addEvent(element, event, delegate ) {
       if (typeof (window.event) != 'undefined' && element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, delegate);
       else 
        element.addEventListener(event, delegate, false);
      }
      
      addEvent(document, 'readystatechange', function() {
       if ( document.readyState !== "complete" ) 
        return true;
        
       var items = document.querySelectorAll("section.products ul li");
       var cart = document.querySelectorAll("#cart ul")[0];
       
       function updateCart(){
        var total = 0;
                    var term = 48;
                    var rate = 7;
                    var amount = 15090;
        var cart_items = document.querySelectorAll("#cart ul li")
        for (var i = 0; i < cart_items.length; i++) {
         var cart_item = cart_items[i];
         var quantity = cart_item.getAttribute('data-quantity');
         var price = cart_item.getAttribute('data-price');
         var payment = amount*((((rate/12)/100)*((1+((rate/12)/100))**term))/(((1+((rate/12)/100))**term)-1));
         var sub_total = parseFloat(quantity * parseFloat(price));
         cart_item.querySelectorAll("span.sub-total")[0].innerHTML =  + sub_total.toFixed(2);
         
         total += sub_total*((((rate/12)/100)*((1+((rate/12)/100))**term))/(((1+((rate/12)/100))**term)-1));
                        newpayment=total+payment
                       
                        
                        
        }
        
        document.querySelectorAll("#cart span.total")[0].innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
                    document.querySelectorAll("#cart span.newpayment")[0].innerHTML = newpayment.toFixed(2);
                                    
                                    
       }
       
       function addCartItem(item, id) {
        var clone = item.cloneNode(true);
        clone.setAttribute('data-id', id);
        clone.setAttribute('data-quantity', 1);
        clone.removeAttribute('id');
        
        var fragment = document.createElement('span');
        fragment.setAttribute('class', 'quantity');
        fragment.innerHTML = '<button id="butt" onclick="one(this);">delete item</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$';
        clone.appendChild(fragment); 
        
        fragment = document.createElement('span');
        fragment.setAttribute('class', 'sub-total');
        clone.appendChild(fragment);     
        cart.appendChild(clone);
                    
                 
               
       }
                
              
       
       
       function updateCartItem(item){
        var quantity = item.getAttribute('data-quantity');
        quantity = parseInt(quantity) + 1
        item.setAttribute('data-quantity', quantity);
        var span = item.querySelectorAll('span.quantity');
        span[0].innerHTML = ' x ' + quantity;
                    
       }
                
                
               
       
       function onDrop(event){   
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
        else event.cancelBubble = true;
        
        var id = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var item = document.getElementById(id);   
           
        var exists = document.querySelectorAll("#cart ul li[data-id='" + id + "']");
        
         {
         addCartItem(item, id);
        }
        
                    
        updateCart();
        
        return false;
       }
       
       function onDragOver(event){
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
        else event.cancelBubble = true;
        return false;
       }
    
       addEvent(cart, 'drop', onDrop);
       addEvent(cart, 'dragover', onDragOver);
       
       function onDrag(event){
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var success = event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', target.id);
       }
        
       
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        item.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
        addEvent(item, 'dragstart', onDrag);
       };
      });
            
         
    
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page"> 
        <div class="grid-container">
         
          <div class="products1">
      <section id="products" class="products">
       <h1></h1>
       <ul>
        <li id="product-1" data-price="3999.00"><div id="item-container">Product 1<br> descr<br>descr </div></li>
        <li id="product-2" data-price="1895"><div id="item-container">Product 2<br> descr<br>descrip</div></li>
        <li id="product-3" data-price="2.99"><span>Product 3</span></li>
        <li id="product-4" data-price="3.50"><span>Product 4</span></li>
        <li id="product-5" data-price="4.25"><span>Product 5</span></li>
        <li id="product-6" data-price="6.75"><span>Product 6</span></li>
        <li id="product-7" data-price="1.99"><span>Product 7</span></li>
       </ul>
      </section>
            </div>
            <div class="menu1">
      <section id="cart" class="shopping-cart">
       <h1>Preferred</h1>
       <ul>
       </ul>
       <p> $<span class="total">0.00</span></p>
                <p> $<span class="newpayment">0.00</span></p>
                </section>
          </div>
          <div class="menu2">
      <section id="cart" class="shopping-cart">
       <h1>Value</h1>
       <ul>
       </ul>
       <p> $<span class="total">0.00</span></p>
      </section>
          </div>
           <div class="menu3">
      <section id="cart" class="shopping-cart">
       <h1>Basic</h1>
       <ul>
       </ul>
       <p> $<span class="total">0.00</span></p>
      </section>
          </div>
          <div class="menu4">
      <section id="cart" class="shopping-cart">
       <h1>Economy</h1>
       <ul>
       </ul>
       <p> $<span class="total">0.00</span></p>
      </section>
          </div>
          </div>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Which function are you trying to call? Your delete button has onclick='one(this)', but the function one is not defined in your code.

Comment: I haven't created a function yet.  I'm not sure how to structure it that would allow that the item to be deleted.  thanks for your help in advance